# Simulcast a .NET Stream

Tags: c#, stream

First off I want to be clear that I am not referring to simulcasting a TCP/IP stream, I want to take the output of a c# stream and have it go to multiple destations.

For example if I had a FileStream(fs) and a MemoryStream(ms) and a FtpStream(ftps) and did something like

```
     ...
     SuperStreamWriter ss = new SuperStreamWriter(fs, ms, ftps);
     ss.Write(helloWorld, 0, helloWorld.length);
}
class SuperStreamWriter : Stream
{
    Stream[] _s;
    public SuperStreamWriter(params Stream[] s)
    {
        _s = s;
    }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        foreach (Stream s in _s)
        {
            s.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }
    }
//Other functions cut for example
}
```

Hello world would be pushed out to all three of my streams. Does anyone know of anything that will give me similar functionality to what I am describing other using that foreach loop on the buffer? Also if the foreach loop is my only/best option would it be safe to thread each iteration of the foreach loop as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything that will simultaneously write to multiple streams, and it would boil down to a loop at some point in any case.

Note that if you go with the threaded implementation (which would certainly be beneficial from a performance perspective), be aware that the default implementation of `Stream.BeginWrite` is *synchronous* - derived classes must implement their own asynchronous logic.  `FileStream` implements its own asynchronous behavior, for example, but `MemoryStream` does not.